# File-system in read-only mode, restart, fsck repeat

Tags: kernel, ext4, udev, read-only

My system works for a while and then eventually falls into "read-only filesystem". The only way to fix it is to restart the computer and hope that it allows me to `fsck` without getting into some kind of kernel panic loop that I just have to pray that the next restart relegates. Right before it happens, I get some messages like this:

```
[   66.065416] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: PCI post-resume error -19!
[   66.065425] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[   66.065571] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: remove, state 4
[   66.065579] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
[   66.066065] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
[   66.066075] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: remove, state 4
[   66.066080] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
[   66.066928] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
[   66.066933] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
[   66.067109] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
[   66.613768] pci_bus 0000:07: Allocating resources
[   66.613793] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 09-3d] add_size 1000
[   66.613797] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 3e] add_size 1000
[   66.613802] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: bridge window [mem 0x00100000-0x000fffff 64bit pref] to [bus 3e] add_size 200000 add_align 100000
[   66.613807] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: bridge window [io  0x1000-0x0fff] to [bus 07-3e] add_size 3000
[   66.613815] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x3000]
[   66.613817] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x3000]
[   66.613821] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x3000]
[   66.613824] pcieport 0000:06:00.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x3000]
[   66.613834] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[   66.613837] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[   66.613840] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[   66.613842] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[   66.613845] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[   66.613847] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[   66.613853] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: no space for [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[   66.613856] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 15: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000 64bit pref]
[   66.613859] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[   66.613861] pcieport 0000:07:02.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[   66.613864] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[   66.613866] pcieport 0000:07:01.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[   70.910819] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1d.6
[   70.910833] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[   70.910842] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a11e] error status/mask=00002001/00002000
[   70.910847] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [ 0] RxErr                 
[   70.984368] pcieport 0000:07:00.0: Refused to change power state, currently in D3
[   70.986977] pci_bus 0000:08: busn_res: [bus 08] is released
[   70.987115] pci_bus 0000:09: busn_res: [bus 09-3d] is released
[   70.987219] pci_bus 0000:3e: busn_res: [bus 3e] is released
[   70.987318] pci_bus 0000:07: busn_res: [bus 07-3e] is released
```

```
[   70.910833] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, (Receiver ID)
[   70.910842] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:   device [8086:a11e] error status/mask=00002001/00002000
[   70.910847] pcieport 0000:00:1d.6: AER:    [ 0] RxErr
```

Sometimes I'll also see messages about `traps: udevd`

```
Machine: 

Dell XPS 15 - 9560 (Purchased in 2017)
Ubuntu 18.04
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Fresh installs
2. Fresh installs of other versions/derivatives of Ubuntu (19.04,19.10, 20.04, Derivative Pop OS)
3. Replacing the SSD

Note: sometimes they fail to install with kernel panics, and I'm not clear on why (I've used the same usb key on another machine)

### Updates

Result of `lspci -tv`

```
-[0000:00]-+-00.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
           +-01.0-[01]----00.0  NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
           +-02.0  Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630
           +-04.0  Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
           +-14.0  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
           +-14.2  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
           +-15.0  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #0
           +-15.1  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #1
           +-16.0  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
           +-17.0  Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
           +-1c.0-[02]----00.0  Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
           +-1c.1-[03]----00.0  Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
           +-1d.0-[04]----00.0  Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
           +-1d.4-[05]--
           +-1d.6-[06-3e]--
           +-1f.0  Intel Corporation HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
           +-1f.2  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
           +-1f.3  Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller
           \-1f.4  Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
```

Result of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`

```
1.15.0
```

Result of `lspci -nn`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:5910] (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 [8086:591b] (rev 04)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem [8086:1903] (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f] (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem [8086:a131] (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #0 [8086:a160] (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #1 [8086:a161] (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:a13a] (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] [8086:a103] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:a110] (rev f1)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 [8086:a111] (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 [8086:a118] (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #13 [8086:a11c] (rev f1)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #15 [8086:a11e] (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM175 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller [8086:a152] (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller [8086:a121] (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller [8086:a171] (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus [8086:a123] (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [10de:1c8d] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:003e] (rev 32)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983 [144d:a808]
```

Comment: I would test your hardware, but you've mentioned a number of off-topic OSes, Pop is not Ubuntu nor flavor of Ubuntu thus off-topic, Ubuntu 19.04 is EOL & thus off-topic, and Ubuntu 20.04 hasn't been released yet being still in development and remains off-topic until released next month.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I have tested my hardware through BIOS and nothing is reported. Is there some other way to test hardware? The problem spans on and off-topic releases.

Comment: I would likely boot *verified on another box* install media and run the memtest program a couple of days (it should complete without issue), I would also open box & do a *cap-check* and visual inspection of the motherboard and components, and more than likely watch the power output of the PSU during memtest looking for consistency (using multimeter). All of this is off-topic and you should only do what is within your comfort/skill level

Comment: You're getting AER (Advanced Error Reporting) correctable errors on device 8086:a11e, which is a PCIe port. Let's see what's connected to it. It's somewhat common to have a comm device do this. Edit your question and show me `lspci -tv`. Disconnect ALL external USB devices and see if there's any change. In Windows, have you installed a driver that lets you read/write to Linux/Ubuntu ext2/3/4 partitions?

Comment: Also, show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer. Dell XPS 13? 15?

Comment: @heynnema It's a Dell XPS 15, 9560. Bios is 1.15.0 (although now that you mention it these problems started around a bios update a few months ago). Also a few months ago, I tried to run a Windows installation off of the usb-c port via external drive. But this is an Ubuntu only machine (not dual boot).

Comment: @guiverc Appreciate the follow-up. I wish I was capable of those things. But software is the limit of my expertise.

Comment: I made a mistake on the BIOS. The latest is 1.18.0 from https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=1pmdc&oscode=wt64a&productcode=xps-15-9560-laptop. The procedure is at https://www.dell.com/support/article/za/en/zabsdt1/sln171755/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment?lang=en

Comment: Please see my initial answer. Report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AER Errors**

You're getting AER (Advanced Error Reporting) correctable errors on device 8086:a11e, which is a PCIe port. `lspci -nn` and `lspci -tv` shows us that device 1d.6 is suspect, but it's strange, it doesn't appear that anything is connected to it.

What's been tried so far:

1. Fresh installs
2. Fresh installs of other versions/derivatives of Ubuntu (19.04,19.10, 20.04, Derivative Pop OS)
3. Replacing the SSD

Normally I'd quote adding a kernel parameter to get rid of AER noise (and I may do so later), but in this case I think we need to check some other things.

**Memory**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**BIOS**

**Note**: Backup important files before upgrading the BIOS

You currently have BIOS 1.15.0. The current BIOS is 1.18.0 and can be downloaded from [here](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=1pmdc&oscode=wt64a&productcode=xps-15-9560-laptop). The BIOS update procedure for Ubuntu is [here](https://www.dell.com/support/article/za/en/zabsdt1/sln171755/update-the-dell-bios-in-a-linux-or-ubuntu-environment?lang=en).

Comment: I've had consistent uptime of over a day after I installed 20.04. I'm going to hold off on additional changes while I'm stable (because I need this machine for other things). I'll update here when I've tried the new BIOS.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen Ubuntu 20.04 isn't released yet, and can't be considered as stable. Go ahead and do the memtest.

Comment: I'm going to follow your counsel here. Just not right now.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen status please...

Comment: I upgraded the BIOS and it's since been running. Uptime of 9 days.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen That's great! Thanks for the update!